# Instantiating expensive object inside Java enum constant

Tags: java, enums

I came across some code which does something similar (simplified for clarity)

```
public enum MyServiceImpl implements MyService {

    A {
        //@Override MyService contract
    },
    B {
        //@Override MyService contract
    },
    C {
        //ExpensiveObject is a complex class which uses DecimalFormat, some regex in the constructor and also ManagementFactory for CPU measurement.
        ExpensiveObject eo = new ExpensiveObject();

        //@Override MyService contract
    };

}
```

What are the performance implications of doing this? Given that MyServiceImpl is a Singleton implicitly, is the cost of creating `ExpensiveObject` a one time thing? Is the price paid when `MyServiceImpl` is first referenced?

Comment: What happened when you tested it? What do you think? Have you tried debugging it? Or adding some `println` statements to see?

Comment: code is legacy beyond imagination (no way of testing/mocking things there) and I haven't seen this pattern before

Comment: The object in question is expensive to create in terms of what?  CPU? Memory? Network? I/O??  The question as it stands is vague.  Does the service contract method require the expensive object to do it's work?

Comment: Nonsense. `enum` was added in Java 5. That's only like 13 years ago (great, now I feel old).

Comment: @ElliottFrisch and 13 years is not legacy for you? It is a huge monolithic codebase as well

Comment: @zencv Sorry, I've been working with Java for a **long** time. Java 7 is eol. So I'd consider anything less than 8 legacy at this point.

Comment: @AmirAfghani to be precise, it is initializing some complex class which uses DecimalFormat, some regex in the constructor and also ManagementFactory for CPU measurement.

Comment: @zencv So it's expensive how?  Again, CPU? Memory?

Comment: I am assuming `DecimalFormat.format()` and  `ManagementFactory
  .getThreadMXBean()` are CPU intensive though I do not have any targeted measurement. `MyServiceImpl.C` is actually called thousands of time by multiple threads. I am currently trying to extract that part in the hope of testing separately

Comment: @AmirAfghani I do not have or never had any control over `ExpensiveObject` - I only could control `MyServiceImpl`. So my question should have been 1) Is `ExpensiveObject` instantiated only once as it is *inside* an enum constant? Is it instantiated *only when first referenced* (not when other constants in the enum such as `MyServiceImpl .B` are accessed). Now I have answers for that by testing in isolation in a separate codebase (as I wrote, the real codebase is not testable directly) :-) **Sorry for the ambiguity.**